# How to make my Cypress project to use local proxy when running on pipeline on gitlab?

Tags: proxy, gitlab, automated-tests, cypress

I am very new in Cypress and i do have an issue. So I wrote tests for a web app that is on stage environment and works only with proxy. When i run cypress locally everything works fine, but what if i want to run the tests on pipeline CI/CD(more precisely on GitLab, because I already configured my project there), any ideas on how can I make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily any GitLab-specific configuration needed here, other than maybe environment variables. Have you checked the [cypress proxy documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration)? If so, is there a specific problem/error you're having?

Comment: Thank you a lot, i don't know how i missed this.